# Как на разных расширениях, загружать разные видео?

Tags: javascript

Путем css display:none это не работает, загружает оба видео. А как на расширении в 768px, можно подменять путь к файлу?

```
    <video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="" class="hero__video hero__video--size_pc">
        <source src="/wp-content/themes/video/1920х1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/wp-content/themes/video/1920х1080.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="" class="hero__video hero__video--size_mb">
        <source src="/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

Comment: Не путайте расширение и разрешение.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю как-то так можно, с помощью JS

```js
const videoSourceMp4 = document.getElementById('video-source-mp4')
const videoSourceWebm = document.getElementById('video-source-webm')

window.onload(() => {
  changeVideoSrc()
})

function changeVideoSrc() {
  let src;
  
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    src = getVideoSrc('big')
  } else {
    src = getVideoSrc('small')
  }
  
  videoSourceMp4.src = src + '.mp4'
  videoSourceWebm.src = src + '.webm'
}

function getVideoSrc(size) {
  if (size === 'big') {
    return '/wp-content/themes/video/1920х1080'
  } 
  
  return '/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024'
}
```

```html
<video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="" class="hero__video hero__video--size_mb">
    <source id="video-source-mp4" src="/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source id="video-source-webm" src="/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

П.С. - Здесь выполнение кода вызовет ошибку.
Я показываю примерную реализацию, а не явную

Comment: То есть, нужно словить какое разрешение у пользователя и исходя из этого выбирать действия.

Comment: Я мог бы так и оставить, но думал что для лучшей загрузки сайта на мобильных, загружать видео меньшего размера

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, свойство **window.innerWidth** возвращает ширину окна, а не разрешение экрана по горизонтали и меняется во время минимизации, изменения размеров окна и открывания консоли. Вам нужно **screen.width**.

Во вторых, теги **source** предназначены для автоматического выбора браузером первого поддерживаемого формата видеофайла из тех, что перечисляются в этих тегах в порядке сверху в низ. В Вашем случае можно обойтись без них:

```html
<video id=video></video>
```

```js
<script>
if(screen.width > 768){
    video.src = "/wp-content/themes/video/1920х1080.mp4";
}else{
    video.src = "/wp-content/themes/video/768х1024.webm";
}
</script>
```